# How to enable mouse in Midnight Commander in KDE3 Konsole?

Tags: kde, opensuse, mouse, konsole, mc

Some time ago I installed openSUSE 13.2 and I don't remember doing anything special (but maybe my memory fails me). Anyway, when I run Konsole, and then Midnight Commander in it mouse works.

I checked if I did it by using gpm, but it looks no -- gpm service is reported as disabled, and `ps ax` does not show any gpm running.

On my newly installed openSUSE Tumbleweed I also have KDE3 Konsole, and when I run MC in it mouse clicks are converted to random characters (i.e. I have the effect of random typing on keyboard).

I tried running gpm (program and service) but it didn't change anything. `mc -x` also didn't do anything. For comparison I ran MC from regular xterm and then mouse works fine.

What am I missing? How to enable mouse in Konsole?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out it is not a configuration per se issue, time passed, and MC assumes some features related to mouse are present in the environment. So it is needed to apply the patch: https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/4063

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem since update. I have found that using $TERM = rxvt and tabulation = XFree 3.x.x solve it
Good luck